# how to display all table th name

Tags: jquery

I have a html table like :

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ABC1</th>
            <th>ABC2</th>
            <th>ABC3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>xyz1</th>
            <th>xyz2</th>
            <th>xyz3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
```

Now my question is how to display the all th name in a list using jquery..
I want to display like this:

```
1. ABC1 XYZ1
2. ABC2 XYZ2
3. ABC3 XYZ3
```

Comment: what do you mean by jQuery, Please explain it in more details

Comment: i want to append the th name in a dropdown

Comment: you need to change the structure of your HTML table. I don't think jQuery is involved in this.

Comment: question is un clear

Comment: Why does your `thead` have *two* `tr`s?

Comment: Where do you want this new list to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each `tr` in `tbody` and add the text of each `td` to `ul` like following.

```js
$('table thead tr').each(function (i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        $(this).find('th').each(function (j) {
            $('ul').append('<li>' + (j + 1) + '. ' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
        })            
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('th').each(function (j) {
            $('ul > li').eq(j).append(' '+$(this).text());
        });
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ABC1</th>
            <th>ABC2</th>
            <th>ABC3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>XYZ1</th>
            <th>XYZ2</th>
            <th>XYZ3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<ul></ul>
```